# Python if loop not executing condition properly while comparing next value

Tags: python, pandas, list, if-statement

I am trying to iterate through a list of positional values that I extracted from a dataframe and assign part number for the position values to another csv column.

Here is an example of my list:

```
[0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

When there is a change of +0.35 or +0.55 that means there is a new part. If there is a change of -0.2 or +0.2 it is still the same part. If it is the same value it is the same part.

The respective output would be:

```
0.3, part1
0.3, part1
0.5, part1
0.5, part1
0.3, part1
0.65, part2
0.65, part2
0.65, part2
1.2, part3
1.0,part3
1.0,part3
1.0,part3
...
```

Now I tried writing a script to do this but for some reason my if statement for changing a part when there is a +0.35 is not working but the rest are.

For example I am getting this:

```
4.75,part 8
4.75,part 8
5.1,part 8
...
5.1,part 8
5.65,part 9
5.45,part 9
5.65, part 9
```

Obviously the only problem is when there is a change to 0.35 it doesnt increment the part number. The rest of the conditions succeed. My code is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv



new_df = pd.read_csv("new_df.csv")


col_list = new_df['builder'].tolist()
#result = [(i,j) for i,j in enumerate(col_list) if col_list[i]!=col_list[i-1] ]
#print(result)
with open('part.csv', 'w', newline='') as layer_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(layer_csv)
    writer.writerow(["position","Part"])
    n=0
    for i in range(len(col_list) -1):
        part_check = col_list[i] + 0.35
        part_check2 = col_list[i] + 0.55
        part_check3 = col_list[i] - 0.2
        part_check4 = col_list[i] + 0.2
        
        if col_list[i] == col_list[i+1]:
            writer.writerow([col_list[i],"Part" + "" + str(n)])

        if col_list[i] + 0.35 == col_list[i+1]:
            n+=1
            writer.writerow([col_list[i],"Part" + "" + str(n)])
        elif col_list[i] + 0.55 == col_list[i+1]:
            writer.writerow([col_list[i],"Part" + "" + str(n)])
            n+=1
        elif col_list[i] - 0.20 == col_list[i+1] or col_list[i] + 0.20 == col_list[i+1]:
            writer.writerow([col_list[i],"Part" + "" + str(n)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
import csv

lst = [0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 1.2, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

with open('part.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["position", "Part"])
    part = 1
    for row in range(len(lst)):
        if row == 0:
            writer.writerow([str(lst[row]), 'part 1'])
        else:
            diff = round(lst[row] - lst[row - 1], 2)
            if diff in [0.35, 0.55]:
                part += 1
            writer.writerow([str(lst[row]), f'part {part}'])
```

---

*part.csv*

```
position,Part
0.3,part 1
0.3,part 1
0.5,part 1
0.5,part 1
0.3,part 1
0.65,part 2
0.65,part 2
0.65,part 2
1.2,part 3
1.0,part 3
1.0,part 3
1.0,part 3
```